# Clojure comment highlights not working in neovim with basic syntax plugins installed

Tags: vim, clojure, vim-syntax-highlighting, neovim

I'm using neovim with `vim-clojure-static`, among other vim plugins. But for some reason when I comment out text in my clojure files they are not highlighted as such.

[image: img of comment highlighting not working]

The plugins I'm using are:

```
Plugin 'tpope/vim-fireplace'
Plugin 'guns/vim-sexp'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-sexp-mappings-for-regular-people'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-repeat'
Plugin 'guns/vim-clojure-static'
Plugin 'guns/vim-clojure-highlight'
Plugin 'oblitum/rainbow'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-classpath'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-surround'
```

Any idea what might be going wrong? Is there other information I can provide here to uncover the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you’re running into a compatibility issue here. According to the notice at the top of its README, oblitum/rainbow is unmaintained, and the replacement for it is [luochen1990/rainbow](https://github.com/luochen1990/rainbow).

So, try replacing `Plugin 'oblitum/rainbow'` with `Plugin 'luochen1990/rainbow'`.